# CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: library "libandroid-support.so" not found in Termux

Tags: android, terminal, su

When running su on termux application, I get error

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: library "libandroid-support.so" not found
```

I tried

```
apt update && apt install tsu.
```

I tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
```

The problem still exist. Any idea?

Comment: When running su, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable needed by Termux packages to find shared libraries get lost.

For a utility script working around that see https://github.com/cswl/tsu, which you can install with apt update && apt install tsu.

Comment: Thanks, the last command in your question solved the problem for me. :D

Answer (score -1):

Try to run:

```
apt update && apt install tsu
```

Then exit the terminal and rest